# Multiple Searches in a single text File

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting, binary-search

So far I have made a program that can search for a single string in a text file. It does give the indexes of the string I searched for. However, how can I search for multiple string in a single text file?

So far if I input "Alice" using the Scanner my output would be:

```
Got a match at line 17

Got a match at line 19

Got a match at line 20

Got a match at line 21
```

However if it is possible, how can I search in my scanner for, Alice, John, Steven as my input and my output to be like:

```
Got a match for Alice at line 17

Got a match at John at line 19

Got a match at Steven at line 20

Got a match at Steven at line 21
```

.

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

    int nnames;
    String[] names;
    String stringSearch = null;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //for(int i=1;i<=3;i++){
    stringSearch = scan.nextLine();

    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("File1.txt"));


    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                
        words.add(line);
    }reader.close();


    Collections.sort(words);
     System.out.println("ArrayList elements after sorting in ascending order : ");
     System.out.println("");
        for(int i=0; i<words.size(); i++)
          System.out.println(words.get(i));


    for(String sLine : words) 
    {
        if (sLine.contains(stringSearch)) 
        {
            int index = words.indexOf(sLine);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Got a match at line " + index);

        }
     }



    System.out.println(words.size());
    }
```

Comment: Define "search multiple strings in a single file". What should be the output for 2 (or more) string search? Are you looking for index that match what with these strings? please elaborate more.

Comment: @amit I have updated the question...I hope you can understand it better? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your `if`-block by a loop over all the Strings you are looking for

```
for(String sLine : words) 
{
    for(String searchWord: searchWords)
    {
        if (sLine.contains(searchWord)) 
        {
            int index = words.indexOf(sLine);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Got a match of "+searchWord+" at line " + index);
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: You can avoid `indexOf` using a _simple for_, not _foreach_ for get the current index of word.

Comment: @MrSmith42 I am confused with that line 
for(String searchWord: searchWords)
Does it mean I have to now declare a new variable called 'searchWords'?

Comment: Store all your words you search for in a `String[] searchWord` or an other `Iterable` that contains the Strings. You can also simply use the `args` array if it contains all the words you search for.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
class x{
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{

    int nnames;
    String[] names;
    String stringSearch[] = new String[2];

 //   Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    //for(int i=1;i<=3;i++){
 //   stringSearch = scan.nextLine();

    stringSearch[0]="hello";   //list of words to search
    stringSearch[1]="world";
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("File1.txt"));


    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {                
        words.add(line);
    }reader.close();


    Collections.sort(words);
//     System.out.println("ArrayList elements after sorting in ascending order : ");
//     System.out.println("");
        // for(int i=0; i<words.size(); i++)
          // System.out.println(words.get(i));

for(int i=0;i<2;i++){
    for(String sLine : words) 
    {
        if (sLine.contains(stringSearch[i])) 
        {
            int index = words.indexOf(sLine);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("Got a match of "+stringSearch[i] +" at line " + index);

        }
     }}



    System.out.println(words.size());
    }
    }
```

if you want to get all search string from input 
then try this

```
searchString=item to search seperated by ','
String[] splits = searchString.split(",");
```